# How do I insert a model into a backbone.js collection in a specific index?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I need to insert a model into a Collection at position Collection.length-2. The last model in the collection should always stay the last model in the collection.

What I tried so far:

I added one "page" model to the Collection "Pages" and then tried to swap them around by changing their sequence:

```
var insertedpage = Pages.at(Pages.length-1);
var lastpage = Pages.at(Pages.length-2);
insertedpage.set({sequence: Pages.length-1});
lastpage.set({sequence: Pages.length});
```

I also tried to remove the last page, then add a new page and then add the last page back in.

```
var lastpage =  Pages.pop();
Pages.add({example1: example2});
Pages.push(lastpage);
```

neither of these worked. The newly added page still appears as last model in the Collection. Do I need to call some kind of order function after this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for the brief answer (don't have time to respond), but look at defining a comparator function.

http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-comparator

Comment: thanks that fixed it! I'll describe in the question description how I did it.

Comment: @NICCAI - Link is dead.

Answer (score 57):

[`Backbone.Collection.add()`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-add) takes an `options` object that supports an `at` key for specifying the index.

> Pass `{at: index}` to splice the model into the collection at the specified `index`.

Example:

```
Pages.add({ foo: bar }, { at: Pages.length - 2 })
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The thing is that my Pages seems to be sorted by the attribute "sequence". Passing the option "at" when adding a new model doesn't seem to change the sequence values. Is there any way I can make them change when adding a new model and then reorder my Collection depending on the sequence?

Comment: thanks , that's very useful, didn't know about the at option before. What fixed it for me was the comparator function, though, so I'll accept that answer.

Answer (score 9):

Along the same suggestion as Rob Hruska, use [`Backbone.Collection.add()`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-add) with `at` in the `options` object.

```
Pages = new Backbone.Collection([
  {id:1, foo:'bar'},
  {id:2, foo:'barista'}  /* Last model should remain last */
]);

/* Insert new "page" not at the end (default) but length minus 1 */
Pages.add({id:3, foo:'bartender'}, { at: Pages.length - 1 });

Pages.at(0).id === 1; // true
Pages.at(Pages.length - 2).id === 3; // true
Pages.at(Pages.length - 1).id === 2; // true
```

You mentioned that `Pages` seems to be sorted by the attribute `sequence`; do you happen to have a `comparator` function defined on the Pages collection?

Another question, did you want to update this attribute `sequence` on ALL existing page models currently in the collection when a new page is added to the 2nd to the last position? Or was that attribute an attempt to accomplish your original question?